# How to send a message on API request discord.py

Tags: python, flask, discord.py

I'm facing an issue while working with a bot and a rest-API. My objective is to send messages via the rest-API using multiprocessing techniques. Regrettably, I've hit a roadblock – attempting to send a message triggers an error, indicating that the targeted channel has a NoneType object.

While I'm aware that using Discord webhooks could be a workaround, I require the incorporation of message components, making webhooks less suitable.

bot.py

```
import discord, asyncio
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Button, View
from discord.utils import find
from multiprocessing import Process
from rest_api import app 

TOKEN = 'xyz'

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

async def say(message:str):
  channel = client.get_channel(1137498510397280377)
  print(channel)
  if channel:
    await channel.send(message)

def flask_runner():
  app.run(debug=False)

proc = Process(target=flask_runner)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  proc.start()
  client.run(TOKEN)
```

Flask.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_file, make_response
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON
import os
import discord, asyncio

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class mess(Resource):
    def get(self, message):

        from bot import say
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(say(message))
        loop.close()

        return 200

api.add_resource(mess, "/<message>")
```

Comment: That's never going to work.  The Flask app and the Discord bot are in two separate processes with two entirely different memory spaces.  They don't have access to each others' objects.

Comment: @TimRoberts, Thanks for the reply, Can you please assist me if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I hesitate to make suggestions, because both apps expect to control their own main loops, and the two frameworks use different architectures.  Discord is async-based, and Flask is thread-based.  You can TRY using a thread instead of a process, but I don't know whether that's likely to work or not.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks, I understand the fact it's hard to achieve this type of structure, again thanks for the reply.